# How to know which files an application is trying to access?

Tags: file-io

How do I know which files and registry keys an application is trying to access?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is your lord and savior. Or FileMon & RegMon if you're running an older windows OS.